# pid file error when starting stunnel

Tags: process, chroot, stunnel

I'm trying to start `stunnel` at my mac os as client. But I'm not able to get it running as I have noticed this reported problem at the stunnel's log file:

```
2015.10.10 16:10:24 LOG5[ui]: stunnel 5.23 on x86_64-apple-darwin14.5.0 platform
2015.10.10 16:10:24 LOG5[ui]: Compiled with OpenSSL 0.9.8zd 8 Jan 2015
2015.10.10 16:10:24 LOG5[ui]: Running  with OpenSSL 0.9.8za 5 Jun 2014
2015.10.10 16:10:24 LOG5[ui]: Update OpenSSL shared libraries or rebuild stunnel
2015.10.10 16:10:24 LOG5[ui]: Threading:PTHREAD Sockets:POLL,IPv6 TLS:ENGINE,OCSP
2015.10.10 16:10:24 LOG5[ui]: Reading configuration from file /usr/local/etc/stunnel/kafka-client.conf
2015.10.10 16:10:24 LOG5[ui]: UTF-8 byte order mark not detected
2015.10.10 16:10:24 LOG4[ui]: Service [kafka-producer1] needs authentication to prevent MITM attacks
2015.10.10 16:10:24 LOG4[ui]: Service [kafka-producer2] needs authentication to prevent MITM attacks
2015.10.10 16:10:24 LOG4[ui]: Service [kafka-producer3] needs authentication to prevent MITM attacks
2015.10.10 16:10:24 LOG4[ui]: Service [kafka-producer4] needs authentication to prevent MITM attacks
2015.10.10 16:10:24 LOG4[ui]: Service [zk-consumer1] needs authentication to prevent MITM attacks
2015.10.10 16:10:24 LOG4[ui]: Service [zk-consumer2] needs authentication to prevent MITM attacks
2015.10.10 16:10:24 LOG5[ui]: Configuration successful
2015.10.10 16:10:24 LOG3[main]: Cannot create pid file /usr/local/var/run/stunnel.pid
2015.10.10 16:10:24 LOG3[main]: create: No such file or directory (2)
```

At my stunnel's conf file I have the pid file configured as `pid = /usr/local/var/run/stunnel.pid`

What exactly is going wrong? Why couldn't be created the referenced pid file as reported in the log?

Any answer is appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Does the directory `/usr/local/var/run/` exist?

Comment: Just created it and it worked. I'm gonna delete/close this question. Thank you @ThomasWeinbrenner

Answer (score 2):

Basically the error was a simple one: just creating the directory `usr/local/var/run/`

Comment: Note that if you are running stunnel chroot, then the pid path in the configuration file is relative to the chroot directory, not the system root directory.